# Trigger file selection on a click of a different button extjs4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How do I open the file selection dialog of a filefield using a different button or component? I tried searching over the internet but I cant find a solution. What Im trying to do is open the file selection dialog upon click of a panel.

Comment: if you want to click one button by clicking another, then there is a way of doing that.

Comment: Did you get my answer, it does what you asked for

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to trigger the click event for the `filefield`'s "Browse..." button at the DOM level.
Simply put, the idea is to get the reference to the `<input>` and launch its click event.

Here's an example (also on [JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fa4bwp7q/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/fa4bwp7q/3/)):

```
var fileField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', { renderTo: 'myDiv', hidden: true });

var textField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
    renderTo: 'myDiv',
    listeners: {
        change: function(btn, newValue) {
            fileField.fileInputEl.dom.click();
        }
    }
});
```

This should open up the file browser when typing into the `textfield`, while the `filefield` remains hidden at all times.

This works even on ExtJS 5.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't. The user needs to interact with the button directly to cause it to open.

What Ext does under the hood is it puts a file input element inside a button, that invisibly matches the dimensions of said button. So when you click on the button, it triggers the file upload. That mechanism is used to provide styling.

Comment: I just want a click listener on the filefield button

Comment: That's not what your question says. It says you want to open the browse dialog by clicking on a panel (not a file field).

Comment: Is there a way that I can click the filefield button without actually clicking it so I can trigger the browse dialog?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to trigger one button's click by clicking another button...then this is what you can do:

```
// .....
buttons:
[
    { 
        text: 'Open File',
        id: 'open_button',
        handler: function()
        {
            // open the dialog box and 
            // do what you need
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Another button',
        handler: function()
        {
            // here you can click the Open File button 
            Ext.get('open_button').el.dom.click();
        }
    } 
]
//  ....
```

Works like a charm. You can even check this **[DEMO](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/docs/Ext.form.field.File.1/viewer.html)**. Inside the `Upload` button handler I am alerting some text. If you click on `test` button, it will actually click the `Upload` button.

Only after some time, that demo is not visible in the Sencha's try website, so you can just copy my code there in the appropriate place.

Good Luck

Comment: The OP is asking about the file browse dialog.

Comment: Fire dialog is opened by button click, so this is not any different

Comment: if you look at his/her comment, that what the OP asked me to provide

Comment: Thank you. But how do I get the id of the button for upload field?

Comment: just like any other button, when you create it you assign it. Look at this page http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File. Just assign an id after `xtype: 'filefield'`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this screenshot: http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/werdender/15522933/44207/44207_original.jpg

Blue color shows the invisible `<input type="file">`.

The file field is above the "Browse..." button. When you click the "Browse..." button, you're actually click the invisible file field.

Programmatically click on the file field is not possible.

But you can create a dirty hack: **http://jsfiddle.net/W2ffW/**

Main input thus will only contain a text value, but you can override its method extractFileInput() etc - this is another question.